# Wso2 IS-Api manager delete oauth token(SAML grant type) once SAML logout

Tags: wso2, saml, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

In wso2-IS After saml login I am using saml grant type in api manager( which is configured with wso2-IS as keymanager) to get oauth token which is of type JWt. Once i logout of wso2 is via saml logout. Still the token is working. how can we make this work, as token should be invalidated once user gets loggedout.